# How to make [i] dynamic using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list there is an array in each list. Now I'm trying to make array `[i]` dynamic this is not working. How to solve it?

**My Code**

```
for (let i = 0; i < result.result.length; i++) {
    $.each(result.result[i].services, function(key, value) {
        serviceList += `<li>${value.name}</li>`;
    });
}
```

Comment: i couldn't be able to understand your query

Comment: I never encountered a JQuery `each` function written with 2 parameters. I think you are confusing it with `Array.forEach`